# Ansible Playbook should stop execution if port is open

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am installing karaf on VM and in my installation process i want to verify if karaf instance is already running and it stop installation process and exit from ansible execution if port is open. currently its doing other way

```
- name: Wait for my-service to start
      wait_for: port={{karaf_port}} timeout=30
       msg: "Port 8101 is not accessible."
```

Comment: but what if you have installed the application and its not running? it would make more sense to me if you checked by another way (like some directory exists or not)

Comment: I am changing existing shell script, So as of now i have to verify port.

Comment: understand, please see possible implementation below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this task to check if the application is already running. If running, it will abort the playbook.

```
  - name: Check if service is running by querying the application port
    wait_for: 
      port: 22
      timeout: 10
      state: stopped
      msg: "Port 22 is accessible, application is already installed and running"
    register: service_status
```

Basically, you are using the module with `state: stopped`, and ansible expects the port to somehow stop listening for `timeout`seconds. if port stays up for 10 seconds (it will stay up since nobody stops the already installed application), ansible will exit with error.

change port to 23, you will see playbook would continue to next step:

```
  tasks:
  - name: Check if service is running by querying the application port
    wait_for: 
      port: 23
      timeout: 10
      state: stopped
      msg: "Port 23 is accessible, application is already installed and running"
    register: service_status

  - name: print
    debug:
      var: service_status
```

you dont need the `register` clause, just added for my test.

hope it helps